# How to prevent empty item in list from being displayed?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am mapping over an array of books and displaying the titles in an `ul` list, but the problem is that, since I have a default value for title set as an empty string, the list renders that initial empty `li` item. Here is my book array:

```
  @observable books = [
    {title:"", owned: false}
  ]
```

And I am displaying the books like so:

```
  <div>
        {this.props.store.books.map((b)=>{
            return (
                <ul>
                    <li>{b.title}</li>
                </ul>
            )
        })}
  </div>
```

How do I prevent the empty title from being displayed?

Comment: Why not check if the title is empty?

Comment: So something like this?

      {b.title != " " ? <li>{b.title}</li> : null}

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1279/)

Comment: In addition to @Dymos answer, wrap the `ul` around the map iteration. Currently your code generates multiple `ul`s with one `li` in each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about displaying the whole thing if the title is empty, you could use `.filter()` on the array, e.g.

```
<div>
    {this.props.store.books.filter(x => x.title).map((b) => {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>{b.title}</li>
            </ul>
        )
    })}
</div>
```

If you want to explicitly exclude the title only and still display other things you could consider turning it's `<li>` in to a variable that you render. e.g.

```
  <div>
        {this.props.store.books.map((b)=>{
            const title = b.title ? <li>{b.title}</li> : null;
            return (
                <ul>
                    {title}
                </ul>
            )
        })}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide empty list simply by using css3 style

CSS

```
ul li:empty {
   display: none;
}
```